# I can't close, Minimize, move my window

Tags: compiz

The buttons seem to appear, but are not clickable when i use Compiz. I don't have this problem with metacity. I would use Compiz, but i want to resolve this bug. Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you been modifying compiz settings with Compiz Settings Manager?

Answer (score 0):

its not a bug, after changing setting it takes little extra time to configure , sometimes hangs if you try to click on other buttons, So after making changes wait till it becomes stable it would take max a minute but not more than that.